# How to create dynamic query to connect different server database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create dynamic query to access different database server.

For example, What I have tried is

```
CREATE PROC spDifferentServer
    @Server1 int,
    @Server2 int
AS
BEGIN

   Declare @Server1IP varchar[MAX] = ''
   SELECT CASE WHEN @Server1 = '777' THEN SET @Server1IP = '[192.168.164.8].[Employee].[dbo].' ELSE '' END

   Declare @Server2IP varchar[MAX] = ''
   SELECT CASE WHEN @Server2 = '888' THEN SET @Server1IP = '[192.168.131.8].[Employee].[dbo].' ELSE '' END

   SELECT
      d1.Name
   FROM
      @Server1IP +''+[Details] d1
   WHERE
      Not Exists (
          SELECT 1
          FROM @Server2IP +''+[Details] d2
          WHERE d2.ID = d1.ID
      )
END
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Normally you created a linked server and query it by using OPENQUERY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't provide a variable to replace the name of an object. For example, the following won't work:

```
DECLARE @o nvarchar(255) = N'sys.objects';

SELECT *
FROM @o;
```

You need to create dynamic SQL and execute that. For example:

```
DECLARE @s sysname N'dbo', @t sysname = N'objects';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@s) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@o) + N';';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

For what you have, this would result in something like this (this is untested):

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT d1.[Name]' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM ' + @Server1IP + N'[Details] d1' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                  FROM ' + @Server2IP + N'[Details] d2' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                  WHERE d1.ID = d2.ID);';
PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL;
```

Your best friend will help you debug it if the syntax isn't quite right.